# Find the Nearest Neighbor To A Given Point in a List of Points in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the nearest neighbor to a point in a 2D(X, Y) grid.

Currently I select a random point with:

```
(x1, y1) = choice(self.rooms)
```

How would I go about finding the nearest neighbor in the list `self.rooms` to `(x1, y1)`?

My list is a procedurally generated list of (x, y) coordinates of around 30 items.

```
print(self.rooms)
```

returns:
[(13, 5), (6, 30), ...] truncated for brevity

I think I could use scikit-learn's KDTree but I have no idea how to implement it. I've tried searching for an answer but all I seem to be able to find is how to use KDTree to return the nearest two points in a list.

Comment: refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html)

Comment: What is `self.rooms`?

Comment: Please show a minimal example of what you're working with and what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a O(N) check with all the points in your database.

```
import math
def get_dist(a,b):
  return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)

p = choice(self.rooms) #your point
n = len(self.rooms)
dist = math.inf #(infinity)
for i in range(n):
   d = get_dist(p,self.rooms[i])
   if d<dist and d!=0: # to avoid the same point
      dist =d
      np= self.rooms[i]
print(np) # nearest point
```

To use this algorithm or not depends on how much data you have, as it is good for small dataset(a sample would be good in the question).

If you want a short implementation, functional approach would be better, like in another answer:

```
p = choice(self.rooms) #point to compare
dists= [(i,get_dist(p,i)) for i in self.rooms if get_dist(p,i)!=0] #all distances
min_dist = min(dists) #minimum distance
np = list([self.rooms[i] for i,j in dists if j==min_dist])[0] # Corresponding point.
```

Comment: Even with a lot of data, the cost to preprocess the points (e.g., to build a k-d tree) is higher than repeated linear searches, unless you plan on doing a lot of similar queries.

Comment: My dataset is only about 30 (x, y) tuples. Updated question to reflect, I'll try this out, thank you.

Comment: Using the above method I get `d = dist(n1, i)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` I think it's due to an issue with unpacking the tuples from the list.

Comment: I realized I needed to use `self.dist` instead of `dist` but now I get  `d = self.dist(n1, i) TypeError: dist() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. `print(n1, i)` returns `(149, 55) 0`

Comment: I have edited the code, you need to check the distance with i^th point, that's `self.rooms[i]`, i is a integer. and you gave 3 arguments by calling self.dist, The problem was dist was both defined as a function and a parameter, my bad. I have edited that too

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I missed `self` in `get_dist`'s arguments. Code works wonderfully! Thank you.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav Great answer. Can you please contribute to this question? Seems to be a great candidate. Any help is appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993686/list-of-neighboors-per-row-as-a-new-column-in-a-datframe-with-two-column-x-y

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of points is so small, simply iterating over the list is fine; no need for a more advanced data structure.

It's natural to use the `min` function, which supports a `key` argument for how the elements should be compared. We can also improve the efficiency a bit by not taking the square root of the distances; the closest point is the same if we compare by squared-distance instead of distance.

```py
def closest_point(points, target):
    tx, ty = target
    return min(points, key=lambda p: (p[0] - tx)**2 + (p[1] - ty)**2)
```

Example:

```py
>>> closest_point([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)], (4, 2))
(3, 4)
```

Comment: Using this returns the same point. `(155, 68), (155, 68)` The point I call is in the list I'm referencing. I'll have to look to find a way to search for nearest point other than itself.

Comment: You can do `closest_point(set(self.rooms) - { (x1, y1) }, (x1, y1))`.