# list of neighboors per row as a new column in a datframe with two column X Y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

In the following data frame:

```
x,y
1,2
3,7
10,4
5,3
7,7
1,6
```

I am trying to find the fastest way to get it done. My simple try was to check if they were within a circle.

```
def check_neighboor(x1, y1, x2, y2 , r):
    return (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 < r**2

dx = df.apply(check_neighboor(df['X'], df['Y'], df['X'].T, df['Y'].T, 5))
```

I know I need to iterate over the entire column.
Any pythonic, pandaish and fast method is appreciated.

sample output (incomplete):

```
x,y, n
1,2, [(1,6),(3,7)(5,3)]
3,7, [1,6][5,3]
10,4 []
5,3  [(5,3),(3,7),(7,7)]
7,7 ...
1,6
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the expected result?

Comment: a column in df containing the ist of adjacent points [(a,b), (c,d),... ] per row.

Comment: How do you define adjacent points? Is the circle thing fixed? or can you use something else? If yes then look into triangulation, scipy package can make it for you and you can get the neighbors from that easily (will be alignment based not only distance based).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of tuple pairs which represent the index of neighbouring points

```
x = df["x"].to_numpy()
y = df["y"].to_numpy()

r = 5

list(
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.add(
            np.square(np.subtract.outer(x,x)),
            np.square(np.subtract.outer(y,y)),
        ) < r**2
    )
    .melt(ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
    .query("value and index != variable")
    .pipe(lambda d: zip(d.iloc[:,0], d.iloc[:,1]))
)
```

Comment: Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL). I think it's not efficient.

Comment: Take the core of it, the 'np.add( ) < r**2', and rework it to the form you need. I don't think you'll find anything faster than that.